# TextView does not show counter variable / App crashes

Tags: java, android, textview, int

today I created a simple android program which has an int to count up, and at the same time the int gets displayed as textview..

However, on running I get the error that the app has stopped working.

This is my code:

```
package com.stoertje.countertje;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Opteller extends Activity {

public int counter = 0;
TextView mTextview;

public void Countup(){

    counter++;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opteller);


    mTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counterdisplay); 
    mTextview.setText(counter); //If i remove this part the app doesnt crash

}

}
```

Any ideas why this does not work? I tried some things out and it seems the that it crashes when i add the line I set the "//" after.

Comment: try this one String value = String.valueOf(counter); 
    
mTextview.setText(value );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Countup() is never called so the TextView will show 0 everytime if it is converted to a String. The variable counter is an int and setText() takes a String. Convert counter to a String.

Comment: Great, thanks guys, the string convert fixed it for me. I did call countup, but forgot to add it to the new version. Will vote this as best answer as it was the first

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mTextview.setText(counter);
```

to:

```
mTextview.setText(""+counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initilize counter into OnCreate method.

```
 public class Opteller extends Activity {

public int counter;
TextView mTextview;

 public void Countup(){

counter++;
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_opteller);
 counter = 0;

mTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counterdisplay); 
mTextview.setText(counter); //If i remove this part the app doesnt crash
```

}

}

Comment: The reason of crash is here mTextview.setText(counter) is a integer but setText expects it to be string. So mTextview.setText(""+ counter); works fine.